# Can I save a Creme Brûlée with a soggy crust?

Tags: sugar, french-cuisine, creme-brulee, blowtorch

I wasn't thinking, and put the top layer of hardened sugar on my creme brûlée last night. Now it's a little bit soggy, and I'm trying to figure out how to save my dessert for a party today.

By the way, I originally used powdered sugar. Not sure if regular or powdered is best

I can think of three approaches:

1. Leave as-is
2. Re-apply another thin layer above the existing soggy layer
3. Re-melt the existing soggy layer, hoping that it sets in crunchy.

Any alternative ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Plus one for basically answering your own question!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before the party, sprinkle some granulated sugar on top. Use a blowtorch (preferred) or a very hot broiler to "brulee" the new sugar. That will cause both the old and new sugar to get browned and crunchy.

I just saw this on a related question. [Alton Brown on Creme Brulee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xxuhrRx0fY). He shows great blowtorch technique, do it just like that and you'll be fine, no need to remove the soggy layer.

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what you need to do. Remember, the "crust" is just caramelized sugar. If it gets soggy, just add some more sugar and re-burn it with a torch.

Comment: You may want to keep the flame a little further from the top than normal for a few passes, just to help re-melt the layer underneath without burning the new top.

Comment: I love to hear after-the-fact success stories! My pleasure. :)